# ManyToOne default value

Tags: hibernate, jpa, default-value, many-to-one

I have an application with default values persisted in the database.
For example, a class Person with an attribute City wich default is "New York" with the id 0.

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  private Integer personId;

  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  private City city;
}

@Entity
public class City {
  @Id
  private Integer cityId;

  private String cityName;
}
```

And in database :

```
+--------+------------+
| cityId | cityName   |
+--------+------------+
|      0 | 'New York' |
+--------+------------+
```

And what I want to do is to save a new Person :

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Smith");
personRepository.save(p);
```

If i try to create a city instance whith id 0 and name "New York" I will have a "TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance" : definitely not a good solution.

If I put a default value in the table definition I will have to reload entity from database after saving it.

I could load the city before saving the Person, but I will have also 2 access to the database.

These two solutions are not good for me because I have to explicitely load City instance from database. Is there a way to do it automatically ? (maybe an interceptor or something like that)

NB: I use hibernate 4 and spring 3.2

Answer (score 1):

> If i try to create a city instance whith id 0 and name "New York" I will have a "TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance"

It should not be so. Perhaps it's caused by the fact that `id` of default city is `0`. Try to use `1` instead.

Alternatively, you can obtain a lazy proxy without touching the database using `Session.load()`/`EntityManager.getReference()`.

Comment: I want to use the city with the id 0 if not specified, not to create a new one.I don't understand what you want to say with 'using Session.load()/EntityManager.getReference()'

Comment: Ok I see : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e836. It avoid database access if not needed, but I have to do it manually before saving.